# XML Youtube, access to yt:accessControl? the character :

Tags: php, xml, api, youtube

I have 
[this xml file](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=muse+survival&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2&category=Music&paid-content=false&fields=entry%28id,yt%3aaccessControl%5b@action=%27embed%27%5d%29&key=AI39si6DSLJq1jAYn0lwKU1--Cdrlr_gZTzzlVo9UPH3WJIZrsBn5HU8REYnEn31-aSZ99az0WNHy9_6FX7458T-sajGlNCzYQ)
and i'm trying to access to the value of attribute `permission` in the tag `yt:accessControl` in php

```
echo (string)$xmlyt->entry->children('yt')->{'accessControl'}->attributes()->$actionAttr."------------";
```

but i have the error

```
Node no longer exists
```

Comment: `yt:accessControl` - yt is a namespace, accesscontrol the name of the node. you have to apply special handling to namespaces. post the XML, post more of your PHP-code.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how SimpleXML works and XML generally is greatly beneficial to doing this...
You can discover things through trial and error and end up with something like this:

```
$sxml=simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$videoID.'?v=2');
$yt = $sxml->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
print_r($yt->accessControl->attributes());
print_r($yt->accessControl[4]->attributes());
```

For instance, this will give you permissions for the first and fifth actions, which happen to be comment and embed ATM (should probably loop through all to identify the ones you're interested instead of relying on the order).

Hope this helps,
aL